# How to find and update in pymongo using user input

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

I am creating a pymongo application that takes user input and uses CRUD methods. I want to create an update method that takes user's inputted data, uses that data to search for the specific file and then updates it with new information.

Here is my current update method:

```
def update(self, data):
    if data is not None:
        self.AAC.animals.find()
        return self.AAC.animals.update({data}, {'$set', data})
    else:
        print("Nothing to update, because data parameter is empty")
        return False
```

What I don't understand how to do is how to take user's input and search and then take another input and use that to update.

If I need to clarify anything, I'd be glad to. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this if your `data` and `newData` has the format of `{"key":value}`.

```
def update(self, data,newData):
    if data is not None:
        return self.AAC.animals.update_one(data, {'$set':newData}) //You can use update_many for all records matching with data query
    else:
        print("Nothing to update, because data parameter is empty")
        return False
```